# Estado HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Can anyone explain this error? I get into this line of code.
List empresas = session.createQuery("from Empresas").list(); of EmpresasDAOImp.java

```
jul 10, 2014 1:17:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [springapp] en el contexto con ruta [/springapp] lanzó la excepción [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction] con causa raíz
org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.altobri.conta.dao.EmpresasDAOImpl.listEmpresas(EmpresasDAOImpl.java:50)
    at com.altobri.conta.service.EmpresasServiceImpl.listEmpresas(EmpresasServiceImpl.java:48)
    at com.altobri.conta.controller.empresaListaController.list(empresaListaController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**springapp-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.web" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.springHibernate" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.altobri.conta.*" />

 <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empresas" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.altobri.conta.model.Empresas</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop 
         key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
  </bean>
</beans>
```

**empresaListaController.java**

```
package com.altobri.conta.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.altobri.conta.model.Empresas;
import com.altobri.conta.service.*;

@Controller
public class empresaListaController {

    @Autowired
    private EmpresasService empresasService;
    protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());


    @RequestMapping("/empresaLista")
    // @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model) {

      List<Empresas> empresas = empresasService.listEmpresas();
      model.addAttribute("empresalist", empresas);
      return "empresaLista";
    }
}
```

**EmpresasDAO**

```
package com.altobri.conta.dao;

import com.altobri.conta.model.Empresas;
import java.util.List;

public interface EmpresasDAO {
    void persistEmpresas(Empresas empresas);

    Empresas findEmpresasById(int clave);

    void updateEmpresas(Empresas empresas);

    void deleteEmpresas(Empresas empresas);

    public List<Empresas> listEmpresas();

}
```

**EmpresasDAOImpl.java**

```
    package com.altobri.conta.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.altobri.conta.model.Empresas;

@Repository("empresasDAO")
public class EmpresasDAOImpl implements EmpresasDAO {

    @Autowired
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void persistEmpresas(Empresas empresas) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(empresas);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Empresas findEmpresasById(int clave) {
        return (Empresas) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(
                Empresas.class, clave);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateEmpresas(Empresas empresas) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(empresas);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmpresas(Empresas empresas) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(empresas);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Empresas> listEmpresas() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List empresas = session.createQuery("from Empresas").list();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return empresas;
    }

}
```

**Empresas.java**

```
package com.altobri.conta.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPRESAS")
public class Empresas {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLAVE", nullable = false)
    private int clave;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE", nullable = false)
    private String nombre;


    public Empresas() {


    }


    public int getClave() {
        return clave;
    }


    public void setClave(int clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }



}
```

**EmpresasService.java**

```
package com.altobri.conta.service;



import java.util.List;

import com.altobri.conta.model.Empresas;

public interface EmpresasService {

    void persistEmpresas(Empresas empresas);

    Empresas findEmpresasById(int clave);

    void updateEmpresas(Empresas empresas);

    void deleteEmpresas(Empresas empresas);

    public List<Empresas> listEmpresas();
}
```

**EmpresasServiceImpl.java**

```
    package com.altobri.conta.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.altobri.conta.dao.EmpresasDAO;
import com.altobri.conta.model.Empresas;

@Service("empresasService")
public class EmpresasServiceImpl implements EmpresasService{

    @Autowired
    EmpresasDAO empresasDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void persistEmpresas(Empresas empresas) {
        empresasDAO.persistEmpresas(empresas);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateEmpresas(Empresas empresas) {
        empresasDAO.updateEmpresas(empresas);

    }
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Empresas findEmpresasById(int clave) {
        return empresasDAO.findEmpresasById(clave);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmpresas(Empresas empresas) {
        empresasDAO.deleteEmpresas(empresas);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Empresas> listEmpresas() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return empresasDAO.listEmpresas();
    }

}
```

Comment: I added @ Transactional implementations

Answer (score 1):

This

```
@Override
public List<Empresas> listEmpresas() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return empresasDAO.listEmpresas();
}
```

is not annotated with `@Transactional`. Down that method stack, you try to invoke a method that requires you to be inside a transaction.

```
@Override
public List<Empresas> listEmpresas() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List empresas = session.createQuery("from Empresas").list(); // needs to be called within a Transaction
     return empresas;
}
```

Also, you are missing transaction annotation configuration

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

(Don't forget to add the appropriate `tx` namespace declarations.)

Comment: Ok I added @ Transactional in the first part of the code you've written and the second below the @ Override but still gives me this error code lina  List empresas = session.createQuery("from Empresas").list(); He says createQuery is not valid without active transaction

Comment: @ProSyth Don't accept the answer if it doesn't work. Can you post the stack trace again, after you make those changes? Edit your question and add it at the bottom. Also, you've again copy-pasted your web.xml and spring xml configuration mixed up. Separate them correctly.

Comment: @ProSyth Take a look at my edit. You are missing a configuration element to actually enable annotation based transactional behavior.